# How to join a table to two other tables with linq in a complex query?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to write a linq query that collects records from several sql tables. The tables and their relationships are given in the image below.
Relationships that are established already through primary and foreign keys in the tables are designated with black lines.
Red lines designate relationships that are only needed for the query in order to limit records to the needed ones.
[image]

Here is my best try for the linq query, that however does give more records as I expected (combinations of unrelated records).

```
            var query = from wastewater in db.WasteWaters
                    join allowance in db.Allowances on wasterwater.WasteWaterId equals allowance.WasteWaterId
                    join chemical in db.Chemicals on allowance.ChemicalId equals chemical.ChemicalId
                    join sample in db.Samples on wastewater.WasteWaterId equals sample.WasteWaterId
                    join analysissample in db.Analyses on sample.SampleId equals analysissample.SampleId
                    join analysisallowance in db.Analyses on allowance.ChemicalId equals analysisallowance.ChemicalId

                    select new QueryModel
                    {
                        WasteWaterName =  wastewater.WasteWaterName,
                        SampleDescription = sample.SampleDescription,
                        Chemical = chemical.ChemicalName,
                        Result = analysis.AnalysisResult,
                        MaxAllowed = allowance.MaxAllowance
                    };
        return query;
```

I think the crucial point is joining the table 'Analyses' to 'Samples' **and** to 'Allowances'.

When I query my db with sql (which I am sure to do correctly) then the result differs from the linq query result. So something must be wrong with my linq query. Below the according sql:

```
SELECT WasteWaters.WastewaterName, Samples.SmplDescription, Chemicals.ChemicalName, Allowances.MaxAllowance, Analyses.Result
FROM ((Chemicals INNER JOIN (WasteWaters INNER JOIN Allowances ON WasteWaters.WasteWaterId = Allowances.WasteWaterId)
ON Chemicals.ChemicalId = Allowances.ChemicalId) INNER JOIN Samples ON WasteWaters.WasteWaterId = Samples.WasteWaterId)
INNER JOIN Analyses ON (Analyses.ChemicalId = Allowances.ChemicalId) AND (Samples.SampleId = Analyses.SampleId);
```

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I would not use Linq to SQL as it is pretty much dead.  I would use Entity Framework if possible.  Then you can have navigations and auto creation of your tables from a template.  I am not certain but Linq to Sql may have the navigation members as I know it has some things EF has.  Where you could do a thing similar to YourObject.Include("ChildObject.ChildChildObject").Select(x => new { (combined properties) });  May not be possible, just a suggestion.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
var ans = from c in Chemicals
          join a in Allowances on c.ChemicalId equals a.ChemicalId
          join w in WasteWaters on a.WasteWaterId equals w.WasteWaterId
          join s in Samples on w.WasteWaterId equals s.WasteWaterId
          join a2 in Analyses on new { a.ChemicalId, s.SampleId } equals new { a2.ChemicalId, SampleId = a2.SampleId.Value }
          select new QueryModel {
              WasteWaterName = w.WasteWaterName,
              SampleDesciption = s.SampleDescription,
              Chemical = c.ChemicalName,
              MaxAllowed = a.MaxAllowance,
              Result = a2.Result
          };
```

Comment: at 'join a2 in Analyses on new { ...' -> I get a wiggling red line and the message: The type of one of the expressions in the join is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: Can you post the classes for Analyses, Allowances and Samples? Or at least the types for all the fields involved?

Comment: a2.SampleId is int? wheras s.SampleId is int -> thus the error! However Samples.SampleId has relations to other tables where non nullable int is needed for SampleId. Is there a way to cast s.SampleId within the join?

Comment: I tried accessing the value of the int? - not sure what EF will do with it, can you try that?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not quite understand your last comment. Surely I can access all my integers with EF, regardsless of nullable or not nullable. Just the linq join does not allow conflcting types. In the meantime I started composing my query based on an sql call (GetDataTableByQuery) and converting that to an IQueryable. Works perfect ... just a lot of tidious typing for the sql. If you think it is interesting, I will post it.

Comment: I meant that I updated my answer to use `a2.SampleId.Value` which removes the nullability from the type, but I wasn't sure if EF would handle that, but you could try it.

Comment: Yes, SampleId = a2.SampleId.Value solved the problem. Everthing works perfectly now!!

Answer (score 0):

I may guess that you need to group your query over wastewater so that you don't have multiple line for the same item.

I'm not sure about it but surely you are not so far from the answer.

Let me know.

Comment: You mean GroupJoin ?,  such as -> join allowance in db.Allowances on wasterwater.WasteWaterId equals allowance.WasteWaterId into WasteWaterGroup

Comment: I mean a group by instruction but i'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: I am not familiar with 'group by instruction' -> can you give some more help with that or a keyword that I could google/search for?

Comment: I think it will be something like that :

group wastewater by wastewater into gr
select new QueryModel{
    WasteWaterName =  gr.key.WasteWaterName,
    SampleDescription = //select in the list,
    Chemical = //select in the list,
    Result =  //select in the list,
    MaxAllowed =  //select in the list,
}